# Should I buy a bow or wait for a reward to obtain it?

Tags: dying-light

I just reached the skill level where a bow and arrows are available for purchase from the Tower safe house vendor.  Should I spend the money or wait to either find them or obtain them as a mission/quest reward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy them.  As I remember the only way to attain the bow in the base game is to purchase it.  There is a slightly better bow you can obtain through the Bozak Horde if you own that piece of DLC (but it will be difficult to obtain until later on when you have more skills) and if you own The Following expansion, you can craft two versions of a crossbow (base and advanced) but it requires you to complete a decent chunk of the story, and the following contains spoilers for the base game, so if that matters to you, you likely won't get around to doing that until you complete the base game.  The bow represents the first (and without The Following, only) ranged weapon that is silent.  It also allows you to retrieve your arrows after firing (they'll stick out of the body so you can retrieve them or you can just pick them up if you miss) so it's quite economical as well.  Purchase it, you won't regret it.

Comment: This is still fairly opinion based of an answer, and it's also wrong. Purchasing is not the only way to obtain the bow. And there are 3 bows, before the crossbow.

Comment: As I remember from my playthrough, the 3 bows are the basic one, which as far as I know can only be purchased through merchants (I know it's possible for the Quartermaster to give you one, but it's random and I've never had it happen, it's available for purchase after survivor level 9) the other two are the harran ranger bow (which I didn't mention in my answer because it is dlc that you purchase seperately.) and the Bozak Bow, which I did detail in my answer, but don't recommend it because of the difficulty of completing bozak at the current level) http://dyinglight.wikia.com/wiki/Bow

Comment: Yeah those are right, and I had the basic bow given to me. I finished Bozak at around level 12 overall, it's a matter of knowing what to do not necessarily skill levels.